# Is it possible to rewrite this example using ghc arrow notation?

Tags: haskell, arrows

I reinvented some sort of 'state arrow':

```
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Category

data StateA s a b = StateA {runStateA :: s -> a -> (b, s)}

instance Category (StateA s) where
  id = StateA (\s a -> (a, s))

  (StateA f) . (StateA g) = StateA $ \s x -> let (b, s') = g s x in f s' b

instance Arrow (StateA s) where
  arr f = StateA $ \s a -> (f a, s)

  first (StateA f) = StateA $ \s (b, d) -> let (c, s') = f s b in ((c, d), s)

put' :: s -> StateA s b ()
put' s = StateA $ \_ _ -> ((), s)

get' :: StateA s b s
get' = StateA $ \s _ -> (s, s)

merge :: (s -> s -> s) -> StateA s a b -> StateA s a c -> StateA s a (b, c)
merge f (StateA a) (StateA b) = StateA $ \s x ->
  let (ra, sa) = a s x
      (rb, sb) = b s x 
  in ((ra, rb), f sa sb)


 test = (flip runStateA) s bar 
   where bar = ((put' 7) >>> get') &&& get'
```

It seems like this definition works as I desired: at least *test 3 5* yields

```
((7,3), 3)
```

Note, that this behavior is intentionally unlike ordinary State monad wrapped into arrow like this:

```
liftKC = Kleisli . const

putM :: a -> Kleisli (State a) b ()
putM = liftKC . put

getM :: Kleisli (State a) b a
getM = liftKC get

foo :: (Num a) => Kleisli (State a) a (a, a)
foo = (putM 7 >>> getM) &&& getM

testKleisli a b = (flip runState) a $
                  (flip runKleisli) b foo
```

as *testKleisli 3 5* returns

```
((7, 7), 7).
```

The point is that one can manipulate state in some 'parallel branches of computation' separately, and then merge it somehow.

I am not familiar with arrow notation, but it is inconvenient here: it looks like it desugars creating new 'branch' for every computation. Is it possible to rewrite 'bar' function (from the where clause of test) using arrow notation?

Comment: shouldn't it be `first (StateA f) = StateA $ \s (b, d) -> let (c, s') = f s b in ((c, d), s')` (note `s'` at the end, not plain `s`)

Comment: @SassaNF No, it shouldn't. It will behave like the latter example otherwise.

Comment: `StateA s a b` is isomorphic to `Writer s a -> Writer s b`, that might be a more appropriate way to look at this rather than comparing it to `Kleisli (State s) a b`.

Comment: but that's kind of the point. will all the necessary laws hold, if you don't use modified state?

Comment: @SassaNF I actually can use modified state, but it gets forgotten afterward. Try to expand (a >>> b) &&& c manually.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I didn't happen to use Writer monad so far, but its state appears to be Monoid. So I don't think it is related somehow to my example. Maybe you meant Reader?

Comment: @user2894391: only the `Monad` instance of `Writer` requires `Monoid`, but since these are just functions where there's a writer on _both_ sides (rather than Kleisli arrows) it's basically all just on the `Functor` level, where there's no `Monoid` needed.

Comment: I'm convinced I don't understand what you're asking, sorry: _"Is where a way to utilize arrow notation here?"_ Do you mean "Is it possible to write `bar` using arrow notation?", or do you mean "Can I compose some other arrows to make this arrow, using arrow notation to fix the plumbing?", or some other thing?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I compared StateA with Kleisli just in order to point at different semantics and to cut 'use Kleisli' yelling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's draw a picture of

```
bar = ((put' 7) >>> get') &&& get'
```

to give us an idea of how to write it in arrow notation.

[image: put' 7 and get' go along on the top line and get' goes along the bottom]

Just as with monadic `do` notation, `proc` notation introduces named variables, replacing combinators such as `>>=` with explicit passing of values.

Anyway, we can see that we need to feed the input, `x`, to the two sides, giving:

```
bar' = proc x -> do
        wasput <- put' 7 >>> get' -< x
        justgot <- get' -< x
        returnA -< (wasput,justgot)
```

or if we want everything to go from right to left, equivalently

```
bar'' = proc x -> do
        wasput <- get' <<< put' 7 -< x
        justgot <- get' -< x
        returnA -< (wasput,justgot)
```

### Testing

I'll refactor `test` for multiple testing:

```
test s b = (flip runStateA) s b
```

So we get

```
ghci> test bar 3 5
((7,3),3)
ghci> test bar' 3 5
((7,3),3)
ghci> test bar'' 3 5
((7,3),3)
```

### Can we write it without `>>>`?

We might be tempted to factor out the `(>>>)`:

```
bar''' = proc x -> do
        put7 <- put' 7 -< x
        wasput <- get' -< put7
        justgot <- get' -< x
        returnA -< (wasput,justgot)
```

oops, no:

```
ghci> test bar''' 3 5
((3,3),3)
```

As you pointed out, your state is localised, and the `put' 7` doesn't thread through to either `get'`, so we haven't managed to get rid of the `>>>` or `<<<` combinator.

I can't help feeling that's breaking some Arrow law or other. Hmmm...

### Broken Arrow law

It took me a while to track down, but after a great deal of hand desugaring and frowning at diagrams, I've found an arrow law staring me in the face that your instance breaks:

```
first (f >>> g) = first f >>> first g
```

If we define

```
dup :: Arrow a => a t (t, t)
dup = arr (\x -> (x,x))
```

we get

```
ghci> test (dup >>> (first (put' 7    >>>     get'))) 1 3
((7,3),1)
ghci> test (dup >>> (first (put' 7) >>> first get')) 1 3
((1,3),1)
```

This is because the localised state in `put' 7` in the second example doesn't make it into the second `first`, if you can follow all those firsts and seconds!

### Conclusion:

You found that arrow notation is less useful for your arrow instance because it assumes it's OK to transform via laws that don't hold.

Sadly, whist very interesting indeed, and extraordinarily diverting, it's not a true Arrow.

Comment: Very exhaustive answer, thanks. But if it is not an arrow (I failed to check laws first, shame on me), then what might it be? I do like its behavior.